# Typescript function to generate a class implementing an interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

My question is on a point I don't understand in a mechanism of typescript: why in the following code, ComposerA is correct and ComposerB is not ?

```
type Ctor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function ComposerA<T extends Ctor>(Target: T) {
  return class extends Target {
    ...
  }
}

function ComposerB<T extends Ctor>(Target: T) {
  return class implements Target {
    ...
  }
}
```

In ComposerB I obtain the error -> 'Target' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

I think there is a concept I haven't understood. Is it possible to realize a function which take an object and implements it. I need implements and not extends, this example is a simplification of my original code and I've already an extend of another class.

Comment: how are you imagine to implement object? (instance), you should implement type in your case type T?

Comment: Interfaces are not objects, interfaces do not exist at runtime, so there's no way for `ComposerB` to receive an interface as a value for its parameter. That's what the error message is telling. `Target`, in both functions, is a value that exists at runtime, but `implements` expect a type, not a value. So, could you explain what do you mean when you say "function which take an object and implements it"?

Comment: In fact, I wan't to implement from a class and not an interface and copy the prototype from the class in the resulting class. I wan't to extend two classes in my function merging the prototypes of two classes: a base class and the Target class. Adding the implements give at typescript the interface which will be used after by the object. I don't know if it is the best solution. It seems that's not the case.

Comment: TypeScript types are [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), and from the class' user point of view, `class implements SomeInterface { ... }` is no different from just `class { ... }`, provided that implementation does conform to the interface. `implements` is useful only to ensure that class implementation does indeed conform to the interface, and in order to do that, there are some restrictions - to quote another error message, "A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members."

Comment: " extend two classes in my function merging the prototypes of two classes" - if I understand properly, you want to `extend` base class (which is absent in your examples), and add methods from `Target` class - then `implements` is of no help, you need to combine prototypes yourself the same way as you would do it in javascript, because TypeScript is only about type-checking the code, it will not do any type manipulation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `implement` anything at run time, but you can add methods to the prototype of the class and change the constructor signature with generics:

```
type Class<T={}> = new (...args: any) => T;

interface Fooable {
    foo(n: number):string
}

function withFoo<T>(k: Class<T>): Class<T & Fooable> {

    k.prototype.foo = function(n: number): string {
        return "foo";
    }

    return k as Class<T & Fooable>;
}

class Blah {
    blah(s: string) {}    
}

let BlahFooable = withFoo(Blah);

let b = new BlahFooable;

b.blah("hey") // ok
b.foo(42) // ok
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBUC8BvAvgPikygDsIB3KACgDo6EAnAcyQC4oESQBKIw9ANwAoIQEsSwCAwBmCAMbQAYgHtlCAEZxo2IVD1RpqqiXYkArgFt1U7qyTAG4pkNwjpZknOCjlJKOVFgAAsVZQx8KgBrdnhkNHR8W1hEFAwoADIoUI0tQh19KEiaMAZlYDLwCBpDZSIDDy8fEmNTS2sGJPtHEiYofIL9BghgMwY-ACIa8eEC1wKhkbHCjiRkuLTM7M0IfGFXITkU1YAhRCC+3X1NBCCqNigup148EX2tYChTm62tOoDg0JUL5BbjCITvKDqOpkSjAn4QMHqGjXW7jIIQEDjXgAemxUGUkSESJqVAALAAmHF4gkiIRAA)

In a more generic way:

```
type Class<T={}> = new (...args: any) => T;

function Mixin<T, M extends object>(cls: Class<T>, mixin: M): Class<T & M> {
    Object.assign(cls.prototype, mixin);
    return cls as Class<T & M>;
} 

class Blah {
    blah(s: string) {}
}

let BlahWithFoo = Mixin(Blah, {
    foo(n: number): string {
        return "foo";
    }
});

let b = new BlahWithFoo();

b.blah("hey") // ok
b.foo(42) // ok
```